# java - equals function wont work

Tags: java, object

NOTE: My English isn't the best so please don't mind too much Grammar mistakes.

Hey there, Java Starter here, anyways i was writing my CPS Test program, and i found a bug i can't figure out. this question may got asked before but i couldn't use the .equals function.

Code:

```
boolean wait = false;
times2 times2 = new times2(0, false);
times2.setTimes(0);
final AtomicInteger times = new AtomicInteger(0);

b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  final AtomicInteger clicks = new AtomicInteger(0);
  @SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Console> startTest;");
    // This if condition won't work.
    if(times.equals(times2.getTimes())) {
      b1.setText("3");
      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)1.0);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      b1.setText("2");
      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)1.0);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      b1.setText("1");
      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)1.0);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      b1.setText("CLICK!");
      times.incrementAndGet();
      times2.setWait(true);
    }else if(!times.equals(times2.getTimes())){
      clicks.incrementAndGet();
    }
    if(times2.getWait() == true) {
      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)10.0);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      JLabel text2 = new JLabel("");

      Font f = new Font(null, Font.BOLD , 0);

      Font size = f.deriveFont(45f);
      double clicks2 = clicks.get();
      double results = clicks2/10;
      text2.setText("<html> Your final Results: <html> " +  "<html> <br> <html>" + results);
      text2.setFont(size);
      text2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

      JFrame end = new JFrame();
      end.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,350));
      end.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(450,450));
      end.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      end.setTitle("RESULTS");
      end.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      end.pack();
      end.setVisible(true);
      end.getContentPane().add(text2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
  }
});
```

times2.java:

```
public class times2 {
    private int times;
    private boolean wait;

    public times2(int times2, boolean wait2) {
      this.times = times2;
      this.wait = wait2;
    }

    public int getTimes() {
      return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(int times) {
      this.times = times;
    }

    public boolean isWait() {
      return wait;
    }

    public void setWait(boolean wait) {
      this.wait = wait;
    }

    public boolean getWait() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
    }
}
```

If you know whats wrong Please respond to this post.

Comment: you did not override equals method. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question but in Java classes are usually capitalized so times2 should be Times2.

Answer (score 2):

If you want for it to work you need to compare like so:

```
times.get().equals(times2.getTimes())
```

or (java 7++)

```
Objects.equals(times.get(), times2.getTimes())
```

`time` is an instance of `AtomicInteger`, `times2.getTime()` is an `int`, casted to Integer.

Those are two different classes.

So to solve it you need to bring both to same type, simply by times.get(), which will produce an int.

Comment: Thanks but does it wil work with times2.getTimes(); too?

Comment: You need to cast AtomicInteger to int, then compare. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should overwrite equals method

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    test2 test2 = (test2) o;

    if (times != test2.times) return false;
    return wait == test2.wait;

}
```

Comment: to override  it in the Atomic Integer?

Comment: Yes, need to override on the Times2 Class